# Site isn't seeing the autoload

Tags: php, facebook, sdk

I'm getting this error:

> Warning: require(/home/wiseman/public_html/path/to/facebook-php-sdk-v4/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/wiseman/public_html/facebook.php on line 3
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/home/wiseman/public_html/path/to/facebook-php-sdk-v4/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/wiseman/public_html/facebook.php on line 3

The sdk has been installed by the host server and I can see the autoload file in exactly the path it's looking for. Anyone know what the problem could be? I'm new to working with facebook and am really green so be gentle! :)

Comment: Notice the emphasized part (have your manually rewrite it or?): `/home/wiseman/public_html/**path/to/**`

Comment: the facebook-php-sdk folder is in a folder named "to" inside a folder named "path". It wasn't originally installed there, but I got the error and moved it into the path/to/ folder. I still get the same error.

Comment: Maybe you should check and change your `include_path` configuration in `php.ini`.

Comment: Oh, I see the folder is a slightly different name than the facebook-php-sdk-v4. I renamed it in the script to match the actual folder name but now I get the error "Class 'Facebook\FacebookSession'" not found. I copied it straight from the facebook dev site. Is it not up to date? If not how am I supposed to figure it out?

Comment: Make sure that your php version is compatible to the facebook sdk 4.

Comment: Yes, are you sure your PHP version is compatible?